# glibc local install on clusters

Tags: cluster-computing, glibc, user-permissions

I am running some algorithm on my machine that requires a version of glibc 2.14 or above. For computing time improvements, I am migrating my whole code to the clusters of my university. However, the glibc version is 2.12 and they don't want to upgrade it. I am therefore trying to directly install the library on my allocated space and somehow link my algorithm to this library. I downloaded the 2.19 version.

I ran the following lines on my allocated space in the clusters
glibc-2.19/configure --prefix=/
make
make install

and I am facing the following issues when I am running the last command
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/myusername/libc.a //lib/libc.a
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `//lib/libc.a': Permission denied

it's trying to create a file in a folder where I don't have permission but I don't know how to override that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Answer (score 2):

> `glibc-2.19/configure --prefix=/`

This is *just wrong*. You likely don't understand what `--prefix` does.

The default prefix is `/usr/local`. For *system* GLIBC, the prefix should most often be `/usr`.

What you likely want is `--prefix=/home/$USER/glibc-install` or something like that.

You should also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Comment: While this answer was helpful, the tone is really aggressive and mean. Please consider how you can phrase yourself in a more friendly way next time.